# Unable to run image from Pi Zero W 1.1 on Pi Zero W 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, image, pi-zero-w-2

I have a Pi Zero W 1.1 and I took a backup of the image which I wrote onto another micro SD card. I tried running this on a new Pi Zero W 2 but it doesn't boot. The green activity light comes on and goes off a few times then stays on.

I've updated the image on the Pi Zero W 1.1 using the update commands.

Can anyone please advise how I can get the image to work with the Zero W 2?

Info from the Zero W 1.1 is pasted below. Thanks.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63+ #1496 Wed Dec 1 15:57:05 GMT 2021 armv6l GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version
Dec  1 2021 15:07:06
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version 71bd3109023a0c8575585ba87cbb374d2eeb038f (clean) (release) (start)
```

Comment: How did you make your backup? Does the original Zero 1.1 boot from the backup card?